# How to assign a permanent unique ID with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone let me know how to permanently assign a unique ID to a field?

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE PrestigeCars.Reference.Staff 
(
     StaffName NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
     ManagerID INT NULL,
     Department NVARCHAR(50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The following code assigns a new id field to to the table called 'myuniqueID'

```
SELECT
    Staff.StaffName
    ,Staff.ManagerID
    ,Staff.Department
    ,NEWID() AS myuniqueID
FROM Reference.Staff
```

This will produce the following table:

[image]

The problem is I would like the unique IDs generated to become permanent.

Can someone let me know if that is possible?

Comment: If you want it, to be permanent, you should create a column with a default value. Then it will be permanent, every time a row is inserted.

Comment: @Nikolaus, can you modify my code to show me how to achieve your suggestion, or provide an example?

Comment: I posted it as answer(unchecked from mobile device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE PrestigeCars.Reference.Staff (
  StaffName NVARCHAR(50) NULL
 ,ManagerID INT NULL
 ,Department NVARCHAR(50) NULL
 , UniqueId NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL default NEWID()
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Important is, that this only works for creating the table. If you want to alter the table, you firstly have to add the Column which has to allow null, then fill the values and at last set it to not null.

Edit:
To add a Column you need the alter table statement, as mentioned in many other posts before:

```
ALTER TABLE PrestigeCars.Reference.Staff  
ADD UniqueId NVARCHAR(255) NULL default NEWID()
```

Next you have to set the UniqueId for the existing rows:

```
UPDATE PrestigeCars.Reference.Staff 
SET UniqueId = NEWID()
WHERE UniqueId IS NULL
```

Last but not least you should set the column to not null:

```
 ALTER TABLE PrestigeCars.Reference.Staff
ALTER COLUMN UniqueId NOT NULL
```

You could add an Unique-Index, if you want to, but this should not be necessary.

Comment: I think might work. Going to test it out on a few scenarios. In the meantime, thanks

Comment: I have just tried the option of creating the table using your example above. However, I realise I need to implement the second option you mentioned. Do you have an example showing the code for the second of altering the table, and adding a column which needs to be null?